# Тормозит RecyclerView при добавлении текста

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, textview

Имеется RelativeLayout с RecyclerView. Выглядит так:
[image]

Код адаптера для RecyclerView (все данные в нем заполняются из JSONObject):

```
public class RVAdapterStats extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

Activity activity;
private static final String TAG = "VainLog";
JSONObject values;

public RVAdapterStats(Activity activity, JSONObject values){
    this.activity = activity;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position){
    int solve = 0;
    switch (position){
        case 0 : solve = 0;
            break;
        case 1 : solve = 1;
            break;
        case 2 : solve = 2;
            break;
        case 3 : solve = 3;
    }
    return solve;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = null;
    View itemLayoutView;

    switch (viewType)
    {
        case 0:
            itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.stats_header, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolder0(itemLayoutView);
            break;
        case 1:
            itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.stats_second, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolder1(itemLayoutView);
            break;
        case 2: itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.stats_third, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolder2(itemLayoutView);
            break;
        case 3: itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.stats_fourth, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolder3(itemLayoutView);
    }

    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    switch (this.getItemViewType(position)){

        case 0:
            ViewHolder0 holder0 = (ViewHolder0)holder;

            try {
                holder0.player_games_played.setText(values.getString("playerGamesPlayed"));
                holder0.player_games_won.setText(values.getString("playerwinStreak"));
                holder0.player_lifetimegold.setText(values.getString("lifetimeGold"));
                Picasso.with(activity).load(values.getInt("playerSkillTier")).into(holder0.player_skilltier);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case 1:
            ViewHolder1 holder1 = (ViewHolder1)holder;

            try {
            holder1.wins_defeats.setText(values.getString("playerWinDefeat"));
            holder1.winPercent.setText(values.getString("playerWinPercent"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            ViewHolder2 holder2 = (ViewHolder2)holder;
            try {
            List<SliceValue> sliceValue = new ArrayList<>();
            if (values.getInt("blitz")>0) sliceValue.add(new SliceValue(values.getInt("blitz"), ChartUtils.pickColor()).setLabel(activity.getString(R.string.blitz)));
            if (values.getInt("ranked")>0)sliceValue.add(new SliceValue(values.getInt("ranked"), ChartUtils.pickColor()).setLabel(activity.getString(R.string.ranked)));
            if (values.getInt("casual")>0)sliceValue.add(new SliceValue(values.getInt("casual"), ChartUtils.pickColor()).setLabel(activity.getString(R.string.casual)));
            if (values.getInt("royal")>0)sliceValue.add(new SliceValue(values.getInt("royal"), ChartUtils.pickColor()).setLabel(activity.getString(R.string.royal)));

            PieChartData dataPie = new PieChartData();
            dataPie.setHasLabels(true);
            dataPie.setValues(sliceValue);

            holder2.chartPie.setPieChartData(dataPie);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            ViewHolder3 holder3 = (ViewHolder3)holder;

            List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
            Axis axisX = new Axis().setHasLines(true);
            Axis axisY = new Axis().setHasLines(true).setHasTiltedLabels(false);
            try {
            Line line = new Line((ArrayList) values.get("valuesLine"));

            line.setHasPoints(false);
            line.setColor(ChartUtils.pickColor());
            lines.add(line);
            axisX.setName("Games");
            axisY.setName("Progress");
            LineChartData dataLine = new LineChartData();
            dataLine.setAxisYLeft(axisY);
            dataLine.setAxisXBottom(axisX);
            dataLine.setLines(lines);

            holder3.chartLine.setLineChartData(dataLine);
            holder3.chartLine.setZoomEnabled(false);
            holder3.chartLine.setInteractive(true);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 4;
}

public static class ViewHolder0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView player_skilltier;
    TextView player_lifetimegold;
    TextView player_games_played;
    TextView player_games_won;

    ViewHolder0(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        player_skilltier = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_player_skilltier);
        player_lifetimegold = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_player_lifetimegold);
        player_games_played = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_player_gamesplayed);
        player_games_won = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_player_gameswon);

    }

}

public static class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView winPercent;
    TextView wins_defeats;
    public ViewHolder1(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        winPercent = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_win_percent);
        wins_defeats = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_win_defeat);
    }
}
public static class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    PieChartView chartPie;

    public ViewHolder2(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        chartPie = (PieChartView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chartGameMode);
    }
}
public static class ViewHolder3 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    LineChartView chartLine;
    public ViewHolder3(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        chartLine = (LineChartView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.chartStreak);
    }
}
```

}

Если убрать строку `holder0.player_games_won.setText(values.getString("playerwinStreak"));`
то этот TextView будет заполняться дефолтным текстом (который я указал в Android Studio), при этом RecyclerView работает как часы. Если же эту строку вернуть, то ресайклер начинает жутко лагать. В чем проблема может быть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по всему у вас тормоза и-за того, что каждый раз при отрисовке ячейки вы делаете "тяжелую" работу по чтению данных из `JSON`. При чём чтение идёт при заполнении каждого поля. Это лишняя работа и она не должна в адаптере происходить. Вам надо единожды извлечь данные из `JSON` и уже готовые данные передать в адаптер.

Проще всего это делать спец. либами типа `Gson` - там вы создаёте класс-модель по схеме `JSON` и считываете `JSON` в эту модель один раз одной строкой. После этого работает с моделью, а не с нераспаршенным `JSON` - так у вас тормозов не будет.

Читать данные из `JSON` руками - это как делать чертежи для ракет на бумаге карандашом и расчёты к чертежам делать на счётах. А сам чёртёж по бумажной почте пересылать и копии также руками делать. =)

Comment: Спасибо :) Интересно, что из-за одной строки может начать тормозить.