# Лаги recyclerview по необъяснимой причине

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Есть в разметке RecyclerView, он заполняется следующим адаптером:

```
public class RVAdapterStats extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> { 
Activity activity; 
private static final String TAG = "VainLog"; 
JSONObject values;

public RVAdapterStats(Activity activity, JSONObject values){
this.activity = activity;
this.values = values;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position){
int solve = 0;
switch (position){
    case 0 : solve = 0;
        break;
    case 1 : solve = 1;
        break;
    case 2 : solve = 2;
        break;
    case 3 : solve = 3;
}
return solve;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = null;
View itemLayoutView;

switch (viewType)
{
    case 0:
        itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.stats_header, parent, false);
        vh = new ViewHolder0(itemLayoutView);
        break;
    case 1:
        itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.stats_second, parent, false);
        vh = new ViewHolder1(itemLayoutView);
        break;
    case 2: itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.stats_third, parent, false);
        vh = new ViewHolder2(itemLayoutView);
        break;
    case 3: itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.stats_fourth, parent, false);
        vh = new ViewHolder3(itemLayoutView);
}

return vh;
}

@Override

  public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

switch (this.getItemViewType(position)){

    case 0:
        ViewHolder0 holder0 = (ViewHolder0)holder;

        try {
            holder0.player_games_played.setText(values.getString("playerGamesPlayed"));
            holder0.player_games_won.setText(values.getString("playerwinStreak"));
            holder0.player_lifetimegold.setText(values.getString("lifetimeGold"));
            Picasso.with(activity).load(values.getInt("playerSkillTier")).into(holder0.player_skilltier);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;

    case 1:
        ViewHolder1 holder1 = (ViewHolder1)holder;

        try {
        holder1.wins_defeats.setText(values.getString("playerWinDefeat"));
        holder1.winPercent.setText(values.getString("playerWinPercent"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        ViewHolder2 holder2 = (ViewHolder2)holder;
        try {
        List<SliceValue> sliceValue = new ArrayList<>();
        if (values.getInt("blitz")>0) sliceValue.add(new SliceValue(values.getInt("blitz"), ChartUtils.pickColor()).setLabel(activity.getString(R.string.blitz)));
        if (values.getInt("ranked")>0)sliceValue.add(new SliceValue(values.getInt("ranked"), ChartUtils.pickColor()).setLabel(activity.getString(R.string.ranked)));
        if (values.getInt("casual")>0)sliceValue.add(new SliceValue(values.getInt("casual"), ChartUtils.pickColor()).setLabel(activity.getString(R.string.casual)));
        if (values.getInt("royal")>0)sliceValue.add(new SliceValue(values.getInt("royal"), ChartUtils.pickColor()).setLabel(activity.getString(R.string.royal)));

        PieChartData dataPie = new PieChartData();
        dataPie.setHasLabels(true);
        dataPie.setValues(sliceValue);

        holder2.chartPie.setPieChartData(dataPie);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;

    case 3:
        ViewHolder3 holder3 = (ViewHolder3)holder;

        List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
        Axis axisX = new Axis().setHasLines(true);
        Axis axisY = new Axis().setHasLines(true).setHasTiltedLabels(false);
        try {
        Line line = new Line((ArrayList) values.get("valuesLine"));

        line.setHasPoints(false);
        line.setColor(ChartUtils.pickColor());
        lines.add(line);
        axisX.setName("Games");
        axisY.setName("Progress");
        LineChartData dataLine = new LineChartData();
        dataLine.setAxisYLeft(axisY);
        dataLine.setAxisXBottom(axisX);
        dataLine.setLines(lines);

        holder3.chartLine.setLineChartData(dataLine);
        holder3.chartLine.setZoomEnabled(false);
        holder3.chartLine.setInteractive(true);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
}

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return 4;
}

public static class ViewHolder0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

ImageView player_skilltier;
TextView player_lifetimegold;
TextView player_games_played;
TextView player_games_won;

ViewHolder0(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    player_skilltier = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_player_skilltier);
    player_lifetimegold = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_player_lifetimegold);
    player_games_played = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_player_gamesplayed);
    player_games_won = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_player_gameswon);

}

}

public static class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
TextView winPercent;
TextView wins_defeats;
public ViewHolder1(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    winPercent = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_win_percent);
    wins_defeats = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_win_defeat);
}
}
 public static class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
  PieChartView chartPie;

  public ViewHolder2(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    chartPie = (PieChartView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chartGameMode);
}
}
public static class ViewHolder3 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
LineChartView chartLine;
public ViewHolder3(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    chartLine = (LineChartView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.chartStreak);
}
}
```

Я снял два скринкаста, на этом видео [тык](https://youtu.be/T4fdn3PAgQQ) график времени работы gpu, на втором [тык](https://youtu.be/LHgzZzEpFQQ) при обновлении элемента экран мигает. На обоих происходят довольно странные вещи. В чем проблема?

Comment: Нормально отформатируйте код в вопросе

Comment: А какой смысл у функции `getItemViewType`?

Comment: @gil9red Для загрузки разных лайаутов в ресайклкер

Comment: Но эта функция возвращает тоже самое, что ей передали и ничего больше не делает. В `onBindViewHolder` можно `switch (this.getItemViewType(position)){` заменить на `switch(position) {` и ничего не поменяется

Comment: @gil9red действительно... Исправлю, спасибо. А насчёт тормозов, что, думаете, может быть причиной?

Comment: Не знаю даже, пробовали логировать код и смотреть где происходят сильные задержки?

Comment: @gil9red нет, но есть одна интересная вещь. Когда удаляю эти строки: holder0.player_games_won.setText(values.getString("playerwinStreak")); holder0.player_lifetimegold.setText(values.getString("lifetimeGold")); , то лаги пропадают

Comment: Все ваши лаги, только из того, что вы парсите ответ на лету.

Comment: @МаксимКузнецов, я же вам вот тут отвечал что лаги от ручного парсинга JSON и вы даже приняли ответ... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657623/17609

Comment: @ЮрийСПб хотелось добавить ясности на видео. Тем более, тормоза оказались от не масштабированной картинки, после уменьшения размера все нормализовалось. В любом случае, вам спасибо, ваш совет не остался без внимания :)

Answer (score 1):

А зачем Вам RecyclerView для данной задачи? Судя по коду, Вы используете только 4 элемента. Перенесите всё в ScrollView, и Вам не понадобиться городить адаптер с пачкой холдеров.